# How to make an anchor element trigger a javascript function on left click, but open a new page on middle click?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vue-router

I noticed that some websites have this functionality, specifically on the Jira website. For example, let's say I'm on the timeline page with the URL - https://atlassian.net/jira/software/c/projects/AT/boards/31/timeline

On this page, left clicking the name of an issue *(an anchor element)* triggers the issue details pane on the right, but overall, the browser stays on the same timeline page, and the URL changes to - https://atlassian.net/jira/software/c/projects/AT/boards/31/timeline?selectedIssue=AT-33 - which is the same URL as before, but with an added query parameter.

However, when I middle click the issue, the browser opens a new tab and navigates to the specific issue's page, an entirely new page with an entirely new URL - https://atlassian.net/browse/AT-33

I'd appreciate if someone can help me understand this behavior in the context of vue.js and vue-router as I would like to replicate this behavior in my single page Vue app.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what is middle click, but let's assume you mean left and right clicks.

When you click on the element using the right click, it triggers [contextmenu event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/contextmenu_event), in this case the browser shows a context menu, but in your case you want to open the details of the issue.

What you need to do is to listen to `contextmenu` event on your anchor, prevent opening the context menu, then add your implementation of opening the details and replacing the url search query like so:

```
yourAnchorElement.addEventListener("contextmenu", (e) => {
   // Prevent the browser from opening the context menu
   e.preventDefault();

   // Add your Vue logic to open the issue details here....

   // Changing the url with the issue id steps:
   const url = new URLSearchParams(window.location.href);

   // append the issue id to the search param
   url.set("selectedIssue", "AT-33");

   // Update the page url without refreshing using the pushState
   window.history.pushState({issueId: 15}, "", url.toString());
});
```

Here is the [MDN docs for the pushState](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History/pushState).

You need just to convert this vanilla JS implementation with Vue, i.e. add the listener for the `contextmenu` event the way you normally do in Vue and pass the implementation function above.